# Jetty: Servlet can't forward to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jetty

I have the following problem: I'm trying to forward the request from the servlet to the jsp page, but I get an 404. When I´m accessing /sites/home.jsp directly, it loads the jsp.

```
    WebAppContext sites = new WebAppContext("src/com/example/blub/server/sites", "/sites");
    ServletContextHandler weblet = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    weblet.setContextPath("/");
    weblet.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new Weblet()), "/home");
    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] {sites, weblet});
    server.setHandler(handlers);
```

.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/sites/home.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

Comment: so the full url of that page is for example http://localhost:8080/sites/home.jsp ?

Comment: Yes

*characterlimit*

Comment: Shouldn't it be /home.jsp? Your root is the sites sidrectory, so your path would look for sites/sites/home.jsp.

Comment: Have a look in Jetty' access log, I'm with @JBNizet here, and it'll show up clear as day in the log.

Comment: I solved it, I had to add the Servlet to the webappcontext instead of creating another handler for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question comes up often enough, so I created an example project of using Embedded Jetty with JSP enabled.

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/

Load up this project into your favorite IDE.

Run the `org.eclipse.jetty.demo.Main` class and then use your browser and open `http://localhost:8080/`

**Quick Tour**

[`src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/Main.java`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/Main.java) contains the part that creates / configures / and starts the embedded server.

Pay particular attention to:

- The JspServlet must be named "jsp" - see `jspServletHolder()`
- The `org.eclipse.jetty.containerInitializers` needs to be setup for the JSP initializers
- The `ServletContainerInitializersStarter` bean needs to be added
- The `InstanceManager` reference needs to be added
- A proper `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` needs to be created
- Set `org.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199` to `false` to use the standard JavaC compiler
- The Classloader for the Context must not be a System Classloader. - see `getUrlClassLoader()`
- The DefaultServlet must be named "default" - see `defaultServletHolder()`

[`src/main/java/com/acme/DateServlet.java`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/acme/DateServlet.java) is an example of how to forward to a JSP from a Servlet.

The DateServlet is [mapped to path spec of `/date/` in Main.java](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/Main.java#L117-L118)

So once you hit `http://localhost:8080/date/` the request will hit the servlet, which in turn forwards to to [`/test/tag2.jsp`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/acme/DateServlet.java#L34)

Comment: Thank you for providing this. It was invaluable.

Comment: Can you provide the same example with web.xml configuration. I am trying to move our old jetty 6.1 to jetty 9.3 or above but getting jsp compilation error. Your example doesn't configured to use WebContext. Seriously in need of help.

Comment: @vibhas your needs are different then this question/answer.  you likely have  a `war` file and want to use `WebAppContext`.  please ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks Joakim will post a new question with comparison of logs as I am unable to render the jsp pages in jetty 9.4 or 9 above. Thanks