# "org.apache.jasper.JasperException" while accessing JSPs in jetty

Tags: jsp, servlets, jetty, osgi

I'm trying to run a webapp with JSPs inside Jetty. I've added the following dependencies for JSP support.

```
1)javax.servlet.jsp-2.2.0.v201112011158.jar
2)org.apache.jasper.glassfish-2.2.2.v201112011158.jar
3)javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar@star
4)javax.el-2.2.0.v201303151357.jar
5)org.eclipse.jetty.orbit.org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
```

However while accessing one of the JSP i'm getting the following exceptions:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /ui/servletcontext.jsp. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
JspFactory cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
JspFactory cannot be resolved

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.glassfish.jsp.api.ResourceInjector cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
PageContext cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
JspWriter cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
JspWriter cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
PageContext cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
_jspxFactory cannot be resolved

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
_jspx_resourceInjector cannot be resolved to a variable

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.glassfish.jsp.api.ResourceInjector cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
SkipPageException cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
_jspxFactory cannot be resolved


    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:299)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've checked lot of forums to check what is going wrong but couldn't find any answer. Please help.

Comment: What version of Jetty?  are you running in jetty-distribution? or using something like embedded jetty?

Comment: I'm using embedded jetty and the jetty server version is 8.X. I got the same error with  version 9.X as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up JSP in Embedded Jetty requires many more steps than just adding the classes to the classpath.

The JSP environment needs to be setup / configured as well.

This has been detailed in a past answer at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20361218/775715

Comment: Actually my project worked fine with Jetty-6. I've updated Jetty to version 9 and jsp implementation to the one glassfish is providing, than things have started failing. I've tried using default jdk compiler, that is also giving the problems.

Comment: Glassfish JSP has been dropped entirely by Jetty.  New releases starting with 9.3 will not include it.  Apache JSP is the only one supported (Glassfish had too many bugs and quirks).  Jetty 6 was EOL (End of Life) in 2010. Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 were EOL in 2014.  Jetty 6 was a simpler time, and it was easy to bake in JSP support, but the servlet spec has had 4 revisions since then, and the JSP standard has also had 3+ revisions since then.  These new revisions have made initializing and configuring JSP support far more complicated.  Read the other answer, and look at the examples linked.